# Koa-compress is not working

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

This is my code for embedding koa-compress middleware

```
app.use(compress({
    filter: function (content_type) {
        return /text/i.test(content_type)
    },
    threshold: 1,
    flush: require('zlib').Z_SYNC_FLUSH
}))
```

And following is my response sending code

```
ctx.body = 'Hello world'
ctx.compress = true
ctx.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
ctx.set('content-encoding', 'gzip')
```

When I hit the URL through CURL I get a simple plain text saying "Hello World" but I believe I should have I got a  compressed string because CURL doesn't do decompression by default. And when I hit the same URL on ChromeBrowser, I get the error saying `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`

When I set content-encoding to gzip, koa-compress should have compressed my response text but it's somehow not doing so. Maybe I'm making some mistake but I don't know what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just retested the whole process once again and I realised that my code was not working because I had manually set `content-encoding`, which I should not have set and it should be set by compression middleware itself. I was making mistakes in **assuming** that response should always be compressed. But what I realised now, after lots of research is that compression works only when the client sends a header with `Accept-Encoding`. If supported Accept-Encoding is `gzip`, the response will be compressed in gzip if it's `deflate`, the response shall be compressed in `deflate` form, and if it's not mentioned response shall be simple plain data. I was receiving plain text in curl because curl does not send `Accept-Encoding` in its default request, but when I sent curl request using following code

```
curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -D - http://localhost:3000
```

then I received the response in compressed form. So my code has been working for always. Just that I **should NOT** have set

`ctx.set('content-encoding', 'gzip')`

If `content-encoding` is set, the module will not run and produce error
so we don't have to explicitly set the content-encoding, it should be set by compression middleware depending on `Accept-Encoding` of the request.

So the correct code to response should be like following

---

```
ctx.body = 'Hello world'
ctx.compress = true
ctx.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
```